# Understanding Python memory management with dict

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

When I writing some Python codes using `dict`, I found out the following behavior of my code:

```
In [1]: def foo(bar_dict):
   ...:     print id(bar_dict)
   ...:     bar_dict['new'] = 1
   ...:     return bar_dict
   ...: 

In [2]: old_dict = {'old':0}

In [3]: id(old_dict)
Out[3]: 4338137920

In [4]: new_dict = foo(old_dict)
4338137920

In [5]: new_dict
Out[5]: {'new': 1, 'old': 0}

In [6]: id(new_dict)
Out[6]: 4338137920

In [7]: old_dict
Out[7]: {'new': 1, 'old': 0}

In [8]: id(old_dict)
Out[8]: 4338137920
```

The `old_dict`, `new_dict` and the `bar_dict` inside the `foo` function are all point to on memory address. There is only one actually `dict` object stored in the memory, even I pass a `dict` inside a function.

I want to know more detail about this kind of memory management mechanism of Python, can anyone points me some good references explain about this? Also, when we use `list`, `set` or `str` in Python, is there any similar behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python names are just *references* to objects stored on a heap. Handing objects to a function call just passes in those references, binding the argument name to the same object.

You created a dictionary object, and bound `old_dict` to that object. You then passed that name to the `foo()` function, binding the local name `bar_dict` to the same object. In the function you then manipulated that object, and returned it. You stored a reference to the returned object in `new_dict`, resulting in two global names referencing the same object.